# Mysterious tableView on device didn't persist in code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 2 problems with my RootViewController which is defined this way:

`@interface RootViewController : UIViewController`

NOTE: I have declared following method from UITableViewDelegate in my RootViewController.m, but they are commented. First it was UITableViewController but later I change it to UIViewController.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

How i wake up my app:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    RootViewController *rootVC = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    [rootVC release];

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

END OF NOTE;

- When i try to build the app he crash with following error

  `2012-06-13 10:34:23.595 Astrobox[540:707] -[RootViewController     tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x151820`

  `2012-06-13 10:34:23.609 Astrobox[540:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception  'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x151820'`
- If I uncomment the methods from UITableViewDelegate it runs on device, iOS 5.1.1 (92206), but my `RootViewController` appears like `UITableViewController` - separators from top to bottom on the screen and because of it nature tableView bounce is enable, I can easy fix my problems here with following code, but I don't accept this as elegant solution.

  ```
  self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
  self.tableView.bounces = NO;
  ```

Comment: can you show `RootViewController ` (image)xib and why are you using `[[RootViewController alloc] init]` use `initWithNibName`

Answer (score 0):

Dont change the UITableViewController to UIViewController..and write

```
RootViewController *rootVC = [[RootViewController alloc] initwithnibname:@"YourXib/Nib name"];
```

instead of

```
RootViewController *rootVC = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
```

that should solve your problem.Also check for the delegate and data source of tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Check nib file of your Rootviewcontroller. It may connected to tableview controller.

Comment: I didn't use xib/nib for building by RootViewController

Answer (score 0):

First Please do not set the table view delegate and data source and check your view is properly loading or not. After that set the following code in view did load..

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.datasource = self;
and implement the < UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource > in your .h file.
and implement all the 4 methods what ever you have mentioned above and don't call it explicitly.
these are the delegate method they will call itself.
```